# I am setting a bunch of Bits into a variable position in a byte and it won't work correctly

Tags: bit-manipulation, capl

I am doing this in CAPL (very similar to C):

```
data[i] = (data[i] & (~mstart)) + (z_Checksum_ldu8[i] & mstart);
data[i] has the value 0x20 and z_Checksum_ldu8[i] is 0x0C
mstart is 0x0F
desired result is 0x2C
actual result is 0x0C
```

while data[ ] and y_Checksum_ldu8[ ] are of the type "byte" and mstart is also a byte (used it as a bitmask).
The rest of the Code is not important, because I can see the result in the debugger. And what I see is not what I want!

---

First of all, why am I doing this?

- I want to set the lsb-nibble exactly to the values of the checksum variable lsb-nibble
- The msb-nibble of data[i] should be the same after the operation ends

But it won't and this is my question: Where is my fault, that the msb-nibble gets set to 0x0 everytime? It's 100% sure, the error must be in that line, cause I can see the debugger value changing to 0x0X (X for checksum) directly after executing this line of code.

Comment: If `data` is a byte, how can `data[i]` be a nibble?

Comment: Presuming your `mstart = 0xf`? Have you tried `data[i] = (data[i] & ~0xf) | (z_Checksum_ldu8[i] & 0xf);` ?

Comment: data[i] is a byte 0x00 and the lsb nibble ist 0x0X and the msb nibble is 0xX0
and yes, mstart is 0x0F, I will try the or solution

Comment: Ok it works, thanks David!
But I am still wondering what the `a + b` does to the bits ...

Comment: Show the values of `mstart`, `z_Checksum_ldu8[i]`, `data[i]`, and the result you're getting, and the desired result.  Then the problem should be clear.  Also, it's a bit unusual to be using `+` rather than `|` to set bits, but I don't think that's causing the problem.

Comment: Yes it's unusual, but I had to do this a few lines above, where it worked so I did Strg-Copypaste. I am sorry for that, but I hope you understand that `+` should not delete bits.

Comment: @R.Joiny, the only thing I can think of is in CAPL your `data[i]` isn't an `unsigned` type. The `|` should ignore any issues with sign extension or carry. The `+` and the `|` should be identical on unsigned types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although both types are unsigned, it only works out using | not + .